# Best Performance Measurement Tool for Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, performance-testing

We have upgraded the rails project from 2.3.5 to 3.2.1 version.Now we need to find the performance improvement with rails 3.2.1. So please let me know one of the best performance measurement tool for our rails application.

Thanks,
Sravan A

Answer (score 3):

I recommend JMeter:

http://jmeter.apache.org/

Once you've designed your tests and started getting the feel of it, you can use this gem:

https://github.com/altentee/gridinit-jmeter

Which is basically a ruby interface for JMeter to let you automate the tests. A nice tutorial for this second part can be found here:

http://blog.gridinit.com/2013/02/21/how-to-load-test-a-rails-app-with-gridinit-jmeter/

Comment: with JMeter is it possible to measure the time taken for completing one request.

Comment: Of course it is, but if all you really need is to measure the time one requests takes, I suggest you take a look at the network tab on firebug/chrome dev tools/firefox inspector.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you think your question was answered!